# Android Background Sockets

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, uuid

So, I am making an app, and I need to have a continuous background thread. It must not stop, the socket has to be always open, so don't please tell me to send data and close it, because I sent an auth request every time, and sometimes the app recieves data from the server. So, would AsyncTask be ok to use?

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask is used for Small fast Background task and not long Background Task for that you should use a Service or at least Thread.